# Space above signature line

Tags: vspace

I'm trying to make a signature block which has enough room above the signature line for a stamp.  But the indicated `\vspace` seems to have no effect.

How can I reserve 3cm above the `\hline`?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand{\signatureline}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{6cm}@{}}
    \vspace{3cm} % Increasing this seems to have no effect
    \\ \hline \\[-.75\normalbaselineskip]
    #1
  \end{tabular}
  \hspace{2cm}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{4cm}@{}}
    \vspace{3cm} % Increasing this seems to have no effect
    \\ \hline \\[-.75\normalbaselineskip]
    Date
  \end{tabular}
  \\
}

\newcommand{\approval}{%
  \par\vspace*{\fill} % Puts signature lines in the same spot of each page for easy stamping
  \section*{Approvals}
  \signatureline{Operator} % Putting \vspace after this doesn't put space between these signaturelines
  \signatureline{Authority}
  \clearpage
}

\begin{document}
Some text
\approval
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an invisible object with the desired height.

I also added `\par` instead of `\\` that's not suitable for the job and `\hfill` instead of `\hspace{2cm}`.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand{\signatureline}[1]{%
  \par\noindent
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{6cm}@{}}
    \rule{0pt}{3cm}
    \\ \hline \\[-.75\normalbaselineskip]
    #1
  \end{tabular}\hfill
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{4cm}@{}}
    \rule{0pt}{3cm}
    \\ \hline \\[-.75\normalbaselineskip]
    Date
  \end{tabular}\par
}

\newcommand{\approval}{%
  \par\vspace*{\fill} % Puts signature lines in the same spot of each page for easy stamping
  \section*{Approvals}
  \signatureline{Operator} % Putting \vspace after this doesn't put space between these signaturelines
  \signatureline{Authority}
  \clearpage
}

\begin{document}
Some text
\approval
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes this works well.  It also removes the hbox over/underfull warnings I was getting.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is to add the same you did to the hline. `\\[3cm]`

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand{\signatureline}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{6cm}@{}}
   % \vspace{3cm} % Increasing this seems to have no effect
    \\[3cm]
     \hline \\[-.75\normalbaselineskip]
    #1
  \end{tabular}
  \hspace{2cm}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{4cm}@{}}
   % \vspace{3cm} % Increasing this seems to have no effect
    \\[3cm]
     \hline \\[-.75\normalbaselineskip]
    Date
  \end{tabular}
  \\
}

\newcommand{\approval}{%
  \par\vspace*{\fill} % Puts signature lines in the same spot of each page for easy stamping
  \section*{Approvals}
  \signatureline{Operator} % Putting \vspace after this doesn't put space between these signaturelines
  \signatureline{Authority}
  \clearpage
}

\begin{document}
Some text
\approval
\end{document}
```